# The following classes couldn't be found -include(fix build path)

Tags: android, android-studio, include, widget

I'm trying to build a widget for my flash light app. I'm using android studio. I right clicked layout and chose widget>app widget and it created required files.

here's light_widget_info.xml which i edited

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/light_widget"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/light_widget"></appwidget-provider>
```

I get

```
 "The following classes couldn't be found
             -include (fix build path)"
```

error.

Comment: Does your xml file in res/xml folder?

Comment: So, it compiles to an APK but can't find in add widget section

Comment: I am probably really late to the party, but have you solved it, I am getting crazy over this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new folder named `xml` in `res` folder, and put the xml file there...

Widget - XML file should be in xml folder
It should point to mainActivity which in layout folder(something like  res/layout/activity_main.xml)

```
android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main"
```

Also you should declare AppWidgetProvider class in your manifest file as follows

```
<receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider" >

   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
   </intent-filter>

   <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
      android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_widgets.htm) is a step by step example you can refer